# int object is not iterable?

Tags: python, typeerror

The program DOES iterate but only until a certain line of code. Then it starts to read the start and stop variables  to be something like 7 and 9?!?! I don't understand what's wrong here. MORE weirdly, It jumps for 7,9 to 48, 51 (the start, stop values). 
Here's the main part of the code : http://pastebin.com/S0FZ3Jk7
and here's the data I'm using with it: http://pastebin.com/rchNJGBq

```
"""
Qualifiers_2.py

"""

#from Qualifier_classes import Qualifier

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Neo\\My Documents\\Python Scripts\\FTC Scouting\\sample.txt'
file = open(file_path, 'r')

Data = []
all_teams = []
Teams_list = []
keys = ['Team Number: ', 'Name: ','Qualifier: ']
qualifier_keys = ['Qualifier: ', 'QP: ', 'RP: ', 'HS: ', 'Matches: ']
team_attr = ['name','number']
UI_options = [1,2]

class Qualifier(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name           = 'Qualifier Name'
        self.rp             = 0
        self.qp             = 0
        self.hs             = 0
        self.num_of_matches = 0
        self.data = [self.name,self.rp,self.qp,self.hs,self.num_of_matches]
    def __repr__(self):
        self.data = [self.name,self.rp,self.qp,self.hs,self.num_of_matches]
        return repr((self.data))

class Team:    
    def __init__(self,name,number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.name,self.number))    

def list_teams(n):
    tTeams = []
    for line in Data:
        check = line.find(keys[n])
        if not check == -1:
            team = line.partition(keys[n])[2]
            if team not in tTeams:
                tTeams.append(team)
    return tTeams

#@param:    team_number , team to find
#@output:   gives back line number in raw Data list
def find_start_team(team_number):
    tcount = 0

    if str(team_number) in list_teams(0):
        for line in Data:
            if not line.find(str(team_number)) == -1:
                return tcount
            else:
                tcount += 1
    else:
        return 'not a valid team number'

#@param:    Start_team_number , the previous team next number
#@output:   the line number for the start and end of the team's acquired info
def find_team(start_team_number):
    try:        
        start_search = find_start_team(start_team_number)
        tcount = start_search
        for line in Data[start_search+1:]:
            if not line.find(keys[0]) == -1:
                return start_search, tcount
            else:
                tcount += 1
    except ValueError:
        return 'not a team number'

def team_data(start,stop):
    temp_data = []
    for line in Data[start:stop]:
        temp_data.append(line)
    return temp_data

#@param: qualifier_key , the name of the category you wish to find
#@param: data , the qualifier info for some team
#@output: returns back the data for the category 
def get_data(qualifier_key, data):
    for line in data:
        if not line.find(qualifier_key) == -1:
            return line.partition(qualifier_key)[2]

#@param: data , the qualifier data for some team
#@output: remaining_data , the remaining data after the first qualifier
#               note: will return -1 if there is no more qualifiers
def just_qualifiers(data):
    tcount = 0
    for line in data:
        if not line.find(qualifier_keys[0]) == -1:
            return data[tcount:]
        tcount += 1
    return -1

#@param: data , array of values for a single qualifier
def update_qualifier(data):
    tqual = Qualifier()
    tqual.name = data[0]
    tqual.rp = data[1]
    tqual.hs = data[2]
    tqual.num_of_matches = tdata[3]
    return tqual

#@param: data , the block of data for the team
#@output: the qualifier data and remainind data
def get_qualifier(data):
    temp_data = []
    for key in range(len(qualifier_keys)):
        temp_data.append(get_data(qualifier_keys[key],data))
    temp_qual = update_qualifier(temp_data)
    data = data[len(temp_data):]
    return temp_qual, data

#Turns our txt file into usable data
for line in file:
    line = line[:-1]
    Data.append(line)

#Creates a tuple for holding the ID of all the teams
all_teams.append(list_teams(0))
all_teams.append(list_teams(1))

#Makes an organized list of the ID for all the teams in a 2-tuple
for team in range(len(list_teams(0))):
    Teams_list.append(Team(all_teams[1][team],int(all_teams[0][team])))

"""*******************
NEW CODE
*******************"""

Qualifiers = []

for team in range(len(all_teams[0])):
    start , stop = find_team((all_teams[0][team]))

    tdata = []
    tqual = []


    #maps the specific teams block of data to tdata
    for line in team_data(start, stop):
        tdata.append(line)
    tdata = just_qualifiers(tdata)
    while True:
        if not just_qualifiers(tdata) == -1:
            tqual , tdata = get_qualifier(tdata)
            Qualifiers.append(tqual)        
        else:
            break    

print Qualifiers

"""*******************
END NEW CODE
*******************"""

file.close()
```

and my TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Neo/Documents/Python Scripts/FTC Scouting/Qualifiers_3.py", line 152, in <module>
    if not just_qualifiers(tdata) == -1:
  File "C:/Users/Neo/Documents/Python Scripts/FTC Scouting/Qualifiers_3.py", line 96, in just_qualifiers
    for line in data:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Include the code in your question with test data imbedded in it so the error can be triggered without us having to save a file and set the path in the code.

Comment: Have you tried to cut this down to a smaller example that still exhibits the error?

Comment: Seconding agf's comment. People here are a lot more likely to help if you don't make them do extra work just to see the problem.

Comment: Ya. Too much code. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @octern: I think in a situation like this, it comes down to the OPs inability to debug, which is when they have no choice but to try posting their entire script. They aren't sure where and how to reduce it. And unfortunately, this requires that some brave soul take it upon themselves to do a code review.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to review your entire program to figure this out, but I did catch one thing at a glance, as part of your traceback:

```
def update_qualifier(data):
    tqual = Qualifier()
    tqual.name = data[0]
    tqual.rp = data[1]
    tqual.hs = data[2]
    tqual.num_of_matches = tdata[3]
    return tqual
```

Did you mean to reference a global variable `tdata[3]` here, instead of your local `data`?

Comment: thanks, and sorry about that :( I'm new to using StackOverflow

Comment: @UnderWulf: Understandable. With the volume of questions on this site, those with higher reputation have seen this situation numerable times and it ends up being almost mechanical how we respond to them. You will get the best answers when you make your questions brief and direct. People on SO will be highly adverse to code reviews of large scripts. Did this answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your `just_qualifiers` method returns either a list or -1 (yuk! why not an empty list?).

You call it once, get the value -1, assign that to tdata, and immediately call `just_qualifiers` AGAIN (why?) like this: `if not just_qualifiers(tdata) == -1:` which is equivalent to `if not just_qualifiers(-1) == -1:` which causes the observed error inside the function -- it is trying to do `for line in -1:`

I strongly suggest that you rewrite that function so that it returns an empty list if there are no qualifiers. Ditto any other similar functions. It is quite safe to iterate over an empty list i.e. `for line in data:` does nothing gracefully if `data` is empty. If you need to check if it is empty or not, you can simply do `if data:` or `if not data:` as desired.